# Can a polygon with an infinite number of sides be viewed as a line?

Tags: limits, circles, polygons

The inner angles of a polygon approach 180º as the number of sides (N) of the polygon increases.

So, if N approaches infinity, we would have a circle.

But... At infinity, we would also have a set of sides with 180º between each other, i.e., a straight line.

So, is it a circle, line or both?

This seems strange, but how could this be explained? Is this reasoning wrong?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

What happens is that the angles of the polygon tend to the tangent lines of the circle at each point.

If you'd like, the circle is a ($1$-dimensional) manifold : it locally looks like a line, but has more sophisticated global properties.

Answer (score 2):

There **is no such thing** as a regular polygon with infinitely many sides. So it has neither this nor that property -- or, depending on temperament, you can say that it is (vacuously!) a straight line and a circle at the same time (in addition to being made of green cheese).

If one takes care to make appropriate definitions, one may talk about the *limit* of a sequence of figures that are regular polygons with ever increasing numbers of sides. In that case, the limit might well be a straight line if your sequence of polygons all have the same *side length*, or it might be a circle is your sequence of polygons all have the same *diameter*.

Comment: Well, there's no such thing in *Euclidean* geometry; I imagine you can pull it off in projective geometry.

Comment: @Christopher: Depends of your definitions. It won't be a _closed_ piecewise straight curve, for sure.